# Modify iOS view while app is in background or in multitask view

Tags: ios, background

I am writing an iOS app that keeps and displays the state of a system.  It basically shows a light whose color represents state:
green/yellow/red light <==> OK/warning/danger

I'd prefer to show accurate state even when the app is backgrounded, and its snapshot is viewed thru the iOS multitask viewer (the view that looks like a rolodex, which you get after double-clicking the home button).  I REALLY don't want to show a snapshot which displays an inaccurate state.

So my question is:  can you change the view (or perhaps the app snapshot) while the app is in the background, so that when it's viewed in the multitask view it shows an accurate state.

I've seen that this is not recommended by Apple:  from [App Programming Guide for iOS](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/BackgroundExecution/BackgroundExecution.html)

> **Avoid updating your windows and views.**   Because your app’s windows and views are not visible when your app is in the background, you should avoid updating them. The exception is in cases where you need to update the contents of a window prior to having a snapshot of your app taken.

However, Apple's music app does just this...if you start playing a playlist, then put the music app into the background, the cover art gets updated as the music app works thru the playlist.  So this functionality must be possible somehow.

The best answer I can come up with after a bunch of searching is to alter my app's view to the splash image prior to entering background operation.  This would ensure that inaccurate state isn't displayed, but also prevents showing accurate state.

Comment: You could change the image on ViewDidAppear or when when the app launches from background.

Comment: @Joakim, but the whole point of the question is updating when the app *remains" in the background.

Comment: How is your app going to continue to execute in the background in order for it to know when it needs to update things? Do you have a relevant background mode capability?

Comment: Yes, it uses bluetooth-central.  I don't need to do a ton of graphics, just change the color of a button.  I would think this is far less work than the music app does when it replaces the album artwork on a new song.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can change the snapshot view immediately *before* the snapshot is taken (A banking app, for example might want to obscure personal information), but you cannot continue to update the snapshot from the background once your app is suspended.  You may want to adopt this approach in order to avoid displaying an inaccurate state; show nothing rather than stale data.

You might also want to consider some other options, such as a "today" widget that contains the updated status or posting local notifications when there is a significant change in status (such as entering the "red" state).

Comment: Is Apple "cheating" then when they update their music app while in the background?  By "cheating" I mean doing something that they won't allow a developer to do?

Comment: Basically, yes.  Apple apps can do a lot of things that your app can't; the clock and calendar apps can update their icons in real time, your app can't. I don't know if I would call it "cheating"

Comment: Not the answer I was hoping for.  Thanks for taking the time.